# Concatenate a character to a TextBox value

Tags: concatenation, telerik-reporting

How to concatenate a character after the field value in a text box in Telerik Reporting?

I tried the below way. Its not working. Is there any way to achieve this task?

```
= {Fields.OlderThan} + " Days"
= {Fields.OlderThan} + Days
= {Fields.OlderThan} Days
```

> textBox24.Value expression [= {Fields.OlderThan} "Days"] is not valid:

If `Fields.OlderThan` = 10
Result should be "10 Days"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of those `{}`. It should work just fine without them: `= Fields.OlderThan + " Days"`.

I also like to handle the case where the field might be `null`, because if Fields.OlderThan is `null` nothing will get printed in your text box:

`= IsNull(Fields.OlderThan,"") + " Days"`